# Import Txt file with two mixed columns

Tags: numpy, sentiment-analysis

I want to import a txt file as below:

```
0 @switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww  that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D
0 is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  School today also. Blah!
0 @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50%  The rest go out of bounds
4 my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire 
4 @nationwideclass no  it's not behaving at all. i'm mad. why am i here? because I can't see you all over there. 
0 @Kwesidei not the whole crew
```

The desired return is a numpy.array with two columns, the `sentiment='0' or '4'` and `tw='string'`. But it keeps giving me error. Could anyone help?

```
Train_tw=np.genfromtxt("classified_tweets0.txt",dtype=(int,str),names=['sentiment','tw'])
```

Comment: What is the error? It can't distinguish between the space after the number and the spaces in the strings. Use a unique delimiter, or try the field length version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with your expression is

```
ValueError: mismatch in size of old and new data-descriptor
```

If I use `dtype=None`, I get

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 22 columns instead of 20)
    Line #3 (got 19 columns instead of 20)
    Line #4 (got 11 columns instead of 20)
    Line #5 (got 22 columns instead of 20)
    Line #6 (got 6 columns instead of 20)
```

working from 'white space' delimiter, it breaks each line into 20,22, etc fields.  The spaces within the text are delimiters just like the first.

One option is to edit the file, and replace the first space with some unique delimiter.  Another option is to use the field length version of the delimiter.  After a bit of experimentation, this load looks reasonable (This is Py3, so I'm using Unicode string dtype).

```
In [32]: np.genfromtxt("stack42754603.txt",dtype='int,U100',delimiter=[2,100],names=['sentiment','tw'])
Out[32]: 
array([ (0, "@switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww  that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third D"),
       (0, "is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  School today "),
       (0, '@Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50%  The rest go out of bounds\n'),
       (4, 'my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire\n'),
       (4, "@nationwideclass no  it's not behaving at all. i'm mad. why am i here? because I can't see you all o"),
       (0, '@Kwesidei not the whole crew')], 
      dtype=[('sentiment', '<i4'), ('tw', '<U100')])
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried it, and got the following error. I am using Python 3. `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_iotools.py in easy_dtype(ndtype, names, defaultfmt, **validationargs)
    893     try:
--> 894         ndtype = np.dtype(ndtype)
    895     except TypeError:

TypeError: data type "u100" not understood`